# Store the details of employee and display the max salary using c++

Tags: c++, class, oop, datamember

I am trying to create a program that stores the data of employees and then displays the highest salary employee separately.

Here, What I had tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

// Using this statement in order to reduce the spam of 'std::' here
using namespace std;

class Employee {
  int ID;
  string name;
  string post;
  long int salary;

public:
  Employee() {}
  // Initializing the class object
  void initEmployee(int id, string varName, string varPost, long sal) {
    ID = id,        \
    name = varName, \
    post = varPost, \
    salary = sal;
  }
  // 'salary' getter
  long getSalary() {
    return salary;
  }

  // The friend function
  friend void maxSalary(vector<Employee> data) {
    int max = 0;

    for (size_t i{1}, len = data.size(); i < len; i++)
      // Comparison
      if (data[i].getSalary() > data[i - 1].getSalary())
        max = data[i].getSalary();

    // After the loop execution, prints the maximum salary
    std::cout << "Maximum salary: " << max << endl;
  }
};

int main(void) {
  int total;

  cout << "Enter the total number of employees: ";
  cin >> total;

  vector<Employee> emp(total);

  for (int i{}; i < total; i++) {
    // Temporary variables to store data in each iteration
    Employee temp;
    string tempName;
    string tempPost;
    int tempID;
    long int tempSal;

    cout << "Name of the employee " << i + 1 << ": ";
    getline(cin, tempName);

    // Clearing the 'cin' in order to prevent the getline skips
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "Post of the employee: ";
    getline(cin, tempPost);

    cout << "Employee ID: ";
    cin >> tempID;

    cout << "Total salary: ";
    cin >> tempSal;

    // Initializing the temporary object
    temp.initEmployee(tempID, tempName, tempPost, tempSal);
    // Pushing the object into the main vector
    emp.push_back(temp);
  }

  // Comparing the vector elements (note: it is a friend function)
  maxSalary(emp);

  return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Enter the total number of employees: 2 // Number of employees
Name of the employee 1: John Doe       // Employee 1
Post of the employee: Manager
Employee ID: 100
Total salary: 15000
Name of the employee 2: Max Ville      // Employee 2
Post of the employee: Assitant Manager
Employee ID: 102
Total salary: 50000
Maximum salary: 50000    // Maximum salary
```

I can find the max salary of that employees... But I want to also display the details of that employee along with the salary. Anyone could help me in re-writing this program?
**If you have some other way to do this you are welcome**

**REQUIRED OUTPUT:**

```
Enter the total number of employees: 2 // Number of employees
    Name of the employee 1: John Doe       // Employee 1
    Post of the employee: Manager
    Employee ID: 100
    Total salary: 15000

    Name of the employee 2: Max Ville      // Employee 2
    Post of the employee: Assitant Manager
    Employee ID: 102
    Total salary: 50000

Max. salary Employee:

Name       Post                ID      Salary
max ville  Assistant Manager   102      50000
```

Comment: Just removed [tag:C] from tags.

Comment: `vector<Employee> emp(total);` constructs a `vector` with `total` elements, 2 in your case. Then you use `emp.push_back(temp);` to add elements to the vector. In the end your vector has 4 elements, the first 2 uninitialized, the second 2 what you expect.

Comment: @mch sorry but I didn’t get you...you have any idea/another way to solve it?

Comment: He's describing the mistake you made.  When you say `vector<Employee> emp(total)`, that creates a vector with two empty entries.  You then use `push_back` in your loop to add two ADDITIONAL entries, making a total of four.  What you should do is create the vector empty: `vector<Employee> emp;`

Comment: And `maxSalary` should not be a method of the class.  It should be a standalone function.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 vector<Employee> emp(total);
```

doesnt do what you think it does. Just do

```
vector<Employee> emp;
```

if you want to reserve space for 'total' elements do

```
emp.reserve(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the index of the employee from the `maxSalary(...)` function. Then you could use that index to print the details of that employee.

You should compare the salary of the current employee with the maximum salary so far. But instead, you compared it with the previous salary, which is wrong.

```
int maxSalary(vector<Employee> data) {
    int max = 0;
    int indexOfMax = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0, len = data.size(); i < len; i++)
        if (data[i].getSalary() > max) {
            max = data[i].getSalary();
            indexOfMax = i;
        }
    }

    return indexOfMax;
}
```

Then you can use this function like following lines:

```
int indexOfEmployeWithMaxSalary = maxSalary(emp);
Employee employee = emp[indexOfEmployeeWithMaxSalary];
std::cout << employee.name << " " << employee.post << ...
```

Also, it looks like there are some other bugs in your code.

First, you set size of your vector as `total`. Then you try to `push_back()` new elements to it. This will push your element to the `total + 1` position of your vector.

If you want to have an initial-sized vector, add your elements via subscripts, like `emp[i] = temp;`. Otherwise don't set an initial size to your vector so you can use `push_back()`.